# Reference for Ostrowski's 1916 Theorem?

Tags: valuation-theory, p-adic-numbers

I am looking for the original reference for Ostrowski's theorem of 1916 that the only valuations on the rational numbers are the trivial, Archimedean, and p-adic valuations.

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski's_theorem`

Wikipedia refers to Koblitz (p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions), but I can't find the reference in there.

Comment: The reference to the *Acta Math.* paper is at the Wikipedia page, but with the wrong year (1918).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barry Cipra is right. See http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02422947
I've changed the wikipedia's entry.

Answer (score 1):

Ostrowski, Alexander Über einige Lösungen der Funktionalgleichung ψ(x)⋅ψ(x)=ψ(xy). (German) Acta Math. 41 (1916), no. 1, 271–284.

Answer (score 1):

According to the book of Helmut Koch "Zahlentheorie" also the following refereence 
is of importance, because there $p$-adic valuations and completions are studied before.
The paper is: Über sogenannte perfekte Körper, in Journal der reinen und angewandten Mathematik $147 (1917), 191-204$.